# CMake: How to make add_custom_command execute only when input is changed?

Tags: cmake

For my project, I'd like to run a command which generates a file that is installed (in other words, the generated file is just a data file, not source code).

I currently have the following in my CMakeLists.txt

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT outputfile.txt
    COMMAND dosomething ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inputfile.txt
                        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.txt
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inputfile.txt
)

add_custom_target(
    run_gen_command
    ALL
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.txt
)

install(
    FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.txt
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/somewhere
)
```

This works fine, but because `ALL` is passed to `add_custom_target()`, the command gets executed every time I run `make`.

Is there any way I could change this so that the command is only run when the input file is changed? The command may take a while to complete, so ideally, it wouldn't be run unless it needed to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `OUTPUT outputfile.txt` may be `OUTPUT output.txt`?

Comment: I don't get your question. `dosomething` depends on `inputfile.txt` and generates `output.txt`, thus `output.txt` is only re-generated if `inputfile.txt` has changed. Is this not the case? Or did I miss something.

Answer (score 2):

Correct this:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT outputfile.txt
```

with this:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT output.txt
```

Then my guess is that you don't need an `add_custom_target` at all. If I am wrong, simply remove `ALL` from `add_custom_target`, and you should be ok.

Comment: Removing `add_custom_target` will not work. Removing `ALL` will make it build only on demand (not included in `make all`)